# LAN connection OK, but No WAN after a reboot. Ubuntu on Mac Virtual Box

Tags: networking, 20.04, virtualbox, lan, virtualbox-networking

LAN OK, but no WAN connection after a reboot.

```
ubu@ubu-VirtualBox:~$ ifconfig 
enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>
        mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.1.251
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 172.18.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed1:1079
        prefixlen 64
        scopeid 0x20 
        ether 08:00:27:d1:10:79 
        txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet) 
        RX packets 6998 
        bytes 1539098 (1.5 MB) 
        RX errors 0 
        dropped 0 
        overruns 0 
        frame 0 
        TX packets 2117 
        bytes 196789 (196.7 KB) 
        TX errors 0 
        dropped 0 
        overruns 0 
        carrier 0 
        collisions 0
    
lo:   flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>
      mtu 65536 
      inet 127.0.0.1 
      netmask 255.0.0.0 
      inet6 ::1 
      prefixlen 128 
      scopeid 0x10 
      loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback) 
      RX packets 3547 
      bytes 317490 (317.4 KB) 
      RX errors 0 
      dropped 0
      overruns 0
      frame 0 
      TX packets 3547 
      bytes 317490 (317.4 KB) 
      TX errors 0 
      dropped 0 
      overruns 0 
      carrier 0 
      collisions 0
```

```
ubu@ubu-VirtualBox:~$ netstat -nr 
Kernel IP routing table 
Destination     Gateway       Genmask     Flags  MSS  Window  irtt    Iface 
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0     255.255.0.0       U    0       0     0   enp0s8
172.18.1.0      0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0     U    0       0     0   enp0s8
172.18.1.0      172.18.1.1  255.255.255.0    UG    0       0     0   enp0s8 
ubu@ubu-VirtualBox:~$
```

Comment: How is the network configured in the VirtualBox settings?

Comment: Bridged Intel Pro.  It has been working fine for well over a year, then I was messing with getting Apache server and it stopped after a reboot.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that "messing with getting Apache server"? Usually a bridged network doesn't need additional work to allow Apache to work beyond setting the adapter's promiscuous mode to "Allow All" ...

Comment: I was trying to connect to apps while my VPN was active using ddns and I am not very good at it.  However, since I've been investigating, it seems the issue may be with a recent NordVPN update and after deleting it my killswitch may still be active with no way to disable it.